# How do I write to a text file in Update function of a script? [Unity|C#]

Tags: c#, unity

I have a Unity C# Script which updates a variable each time the Update function is called. I would like to know how to write to a file from the update function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I wholeheartedly agree with @Jon on this one I'm still going to answer your question. The following class will write to a file in the Update method. Have fun with it.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
public class VeryBadIdea : MonoBehaviour {

    private string filename = "WeWLad.txt";
    private float some_variable;
    private string textToWrite = "Variables : ";
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        some_variable += Time.deltaTime;//update the variable with something;
        textToWrite = textToWrite + " " + some_variable.ToString();//create a proper string so we can read the file afterwards
        File.AppendAllText(filename, textToWrite);//write to the file. No need to call Flush or Close. Note this does NOT overwrite the file every time you restart the game
    }
}
```

Alternatively this might be a better solution.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class SlightlyBetterIdea : MonoBehaviour {
    List<SomeDataToWrite> listToHoldData;
    private float var1,var2 ;// Some variables to increment;
    private string filename = "WeWLad.txt";
    void Start()
    {
        listToHoldData = new List<SomeDataToWrite>();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        //Increment the variables
        var1 += Time.deltaTime;
        var2 += Time.deltaTime;
        //Add them to our handy dandy list
        listToHoldData.Add(new SomeDataToWrite(var1, var2));
    }
    void OnApplicationQuit()//Now that we are quiting the application we can write our data to a file
    {
        string textToWrite="GLORIOUS DATA" +"\r\n";
        foreach(SomeDataToWrite data in listToHoldData)
        {
            textToWrite = textToWrite + " x:" + data.x + " y:" + data.y +"\r\n"; 
        }
        File.AppendAllText(filename, textToWrite);
    }
     internal class SomeDataToWrite
    {
        internal float x;
        internal float y;
        internal SomeDataToWrite(float x, float y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't this create any thread exceptions?
And I'm guessing you're using the `FileStream` class?

Comment: Why would you guess that he uses the filestream class? There's no reference to it anywhere in the code, he's using File.AppendAllText as the code states. Also why would it create thread exceptions? There is no threading going on in it.

Comment: I'm using the File class as you can see from the code not the FileStream class. What AppendAllText does under the hood you should ask Microsoft :D. Besides AppendAllText is guaranteed to close the file handle even if a exception is raised so you dont have anything to worry.

Comment: You don't have to ask Microsoft, you can just look it up here:  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/System/io/file.cs

And it uses StreamWriter internally.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but as far as I understand, the update method will run on multiple threads won't it? So each time the file will be opened on multiple threads right?
Also my bad didn't read it carefully. I'm trying to write it into an array and then save it now though. But I still wanted to know what the best practice would be in cases like these apart from using an array.

Comment: As far as I know AppendAllText is thread safe and will not cause such problems. As for the update method running on multiple threads I dont think so. At best unity has 1 thread for rendering and 1 for physics.

Comment: @user3927312 no, that is not correct. All the Monobehaviour methods in Unity typically run on a single thread. There's a separate loading thread and some multithreading under the hood in the physics and rendering systems, but that's about it unless you manually start a new thread of your own.

Comment: Does this apply to the player or for the editor as well? (The single thread fact I mean)

Comment: If there was a for loop inside the main thread does that create another thread? Because I've just come across something like that and that seems to be the only reasonable explanation to me.

Comment: look no offence or anything but if you asking with help on how to write to files you are far away from understanding threads. Btw check my second example it might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I get what you mean. I'm a little rusty with C# and I wasn't very sure of how Unity works with files. But if you'd help me there's something I'd like to figure out with the Update function and multithreading.

Comment: @UriPopov The second part of the answer gave me exactly what I needed though thanks (`OnApplicationQuit`).  I figure I could open a StreamWriter in the `Start` method and write into it in the `Update` method and `Close` it in the `OnApplicationQuit()` method.

Comment: Unity uses mono so files are like in any other c# app. Updates do no start threads however you are free to strat a thread yourself that does some work again just like any other c# app

Comment: This is not exactly related to my posted question but here's a link to the update function I used.
http://pastebin.com/eKK8x8qx
I have an `i++` statement there in the `else if` conditional. When it's at the bottom of the if else block (as in the paste), it gives me a sharing violation error multiple times (doesn't stop). When it's at the top of the block it gives me an array index out of bounds exception as expected. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: unrelated questions should be asked in a new question.

Answer (score 4):

You do not want to write to a file inside of Update().  That is bad design, and ridiculous.  Instead, you may want to consider writing to memory in your Update() function -- and then dumping this data to file at a reasonable opportunity.

Comment: I actually only need to do this to cache the values of a sin function. I'll put the values into an array and remove the file writing component. i just need a quick way to record around  500-1000 values and save it.

Comment: Create a function that will write your data to file, and only call it once, when needed.